# Sup inf function $\ \frac{(\pi^2-x^2)\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)} $

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I have to determine sup and inf of the following function:

$$\   \frac{(\pi^2-x^2)\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)} ~~~~~~~~ f:(-\pi, \pi) \rightarrow ~\mathbb{R}$$

1) I thought of derivatiove and comparison to $0$, however this equation seems to be too complicated, there have to be an easier option.

2) I thought of Taylor series in $\ \pi$

3) Result of my thoughts: I'm stuck.

I would appreciate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative. You'll see that you can simplify its numerator with $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ and then divide the numerator and denominator by $1+\cos(x)$ to arrive at
$$f'(x)=\frac{-x^2-2x\sin(x)+\pi^2}{1+\cos(x)} $$
The numerator is $-x^2-2x\sin(x)+\pi^2=\pi^2+\sin^2(x)-(x+\sin(x))^2$. Since $g(x)=x+\sin(x)$ is an increasing function (check by taking the derivative), $-\pi=g(-\pi)<g(x)<g(\pi)=\pi$ for $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$. Thus, $(x+\sin(x))<\pi^2$ which means that the numerator is positive, $f'(x)>0$ for $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$, and $f$ is strictly increasing in the interval. So
$$\sup\{f(x):-\pi<x<\pi\}=\lim_{x\to \pi^-}f(x) \\
\inf\{f(x):-\pi<x<\pi\}=\lim_{x\to -\pi^+}f(x) $$
**Update:** Since $f$ is odd on the interval, the second limit is the negative of the first limit. For the first limit, make the substitution $y=\pi-x\to 0^+$ as $x\to \pi^-$. So $x=\pi-y$, and the limit becomes
$$\lim_{x\to \pi^-}f(x)=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{y(2\pi-y)\sin(y)}{1-\cos(y)}=2\pi\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{y^2}{1-\cos y}\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\sin y}{y} $$
Can you find the last two limits?

Comment: Thank you for yor solution, I understand that. However, how can I determine the limits? Both of them seem to approach 0.

Comment: Could you give me a hand with this limits?

Comment: @Question see my update

Comment: $\ \lim_{y=0^+}  \frac{\sin(y)}{y} = 1 $  However, for me, $\ 2\pi \lim_{y=0^+} \frac{y^2}{1-\cos(y)}  = 0 $

Comment: How did you split it in two limits?

Comment: @Question Using $\lim f(x)\cdot\lim g(x)=\lim(f(x)g(x))$. For the first limit, apply L'Hospital's rule once.

Comment: Thank you, the result of the last equation becomes quite clear. However, how did you substitute the second equation? I mean, for example, why 1 **-** $\ \cos(y) $. I don't understand also how you got the last equation: where is $\ \frac{-y^2\sin(y)}{1-\cos(y)} $ from the second multiplication?

Comment: Addtionally, how can you see that the function is odd?

Comment: @Question Odd function means $f(-x)=-f(x)$. So check this equality is true. We substitute $x=\pi-y$. So $\sin(\pi-y)=\sin(y)$ and $\cos(\pi-y)=-\cos(y)$. These are properties of trig. functions.